# Maven and Dockerfile - download dependencies on container creation

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile

I want to run tests on Java + TestNG in Docker container with Maven.
I am trying to make Maven download all dependencies while I create an image via Dockerfile. So it shouldn't download it on a container run.

I have two variants of Dockerfile which are not working properly.

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-ibmjava-8

WORKDIR /tests

COPY . .

RUN mvn dependency:resolve -q

CMD mvn -Dtest=SimpleTest test
```

Here Maven downloads dependencies in RUN while the image is creating and downloads it again when the container is running. о_О

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-ibmjava-8

WORKDIR /tests

COPY . .

RUN mvn install -q

CMD mvn -Dtest=SimpleTest test
```

Here Maven is trying not only to download dependencies but launch tests on RUN stage.

How can I only download Maven dependencies once while I create the image (on RUN stage) and launch tests without downloading dependencies again on the container run?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-ibmjava-8

WORKDIR /tests

COPY . .

RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

CMD mvn --offline -Dtest=SimpleTest test
```

Comment: Nope, fails with: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6 has not been downloaded from it before.

Comment: if it does not work then you have to specify these additional dependencies for prefetch. Official plugin allows to add these via `<includeArtifactIds>`. Alternatively, you can use this plugin https://github.com/qaware/go-offline-maven-plugin and specify additional dependencies for pre-fetching in `<dynamicDependencies>`.